# Hive table not being populated with data from staging table

Tags: mysql, sql, csv, hadoop, hive

I'm having an issue I was hoping someone could help me with, I believe its due to how my tables are being partitioned but I'm struggling to come up with a solution.

I have created a table such as the example one below

```
CREATE TABLE Demo
(time timestamp COMMENT 'timestamp in format yyyymmddTss:mm:hh', 
exampleId varchar(6) COMMENT 'example field'
example2 varchar(10) COMMENT 'example field'
example3 varchar(50) COMMENT 'example field'
example4 varchar(50) COMMENT 'example field'
)
COMMENT 'A table to demonstrate my problem'
PARTITIONED BY (TRAN_DATE DATE COMMENT 'Transaction Date') 
CLUSTERED BY (exampleId)
SORTED BY (exampleId) INTO 24 BUCKETS
stored as orc;
```

And I am then trying to copy data from a CSV file into a table using an external table such as below

```
Drop TABLE Demo_staging

CREATE TABLE Demo_staging
(time timestamp COMMENT 'timestamp in format yyyymmddTss:mm:hh', 
 exampleId varchar(6) COMMENT 'example field'
 example2 varchar(10) COMMENT 'example field'
 example3 varchar(50) COMMENT 'example field'
 example4 varchar(50) COMMENT 'example field'
 )
 COMMENT 'The staging table to demonstrate my problem'
 row format delimited fields terminated by ',' null defined as '\001'
 STORED AS TEXTFILE 
 LOCATION '${appPath}/raw'
 tblproperties ("skip.header.line.count"="1", "skip.footer.line.count"="2");
 insert overwrite table Demo partition (TRAN_DATE = ${day}) SELECT * FROM Demo_staging;
```

The value in TRAN_DATE should be a date format of format YYYYMMDD which is derived from the field time in which all the values are set to 2015-06-20T00:00:00 but i'm not sure how TRAN_DATE is supposed to get this value. The value of ${day} is 20150620. I've tried using the following as a test to see the data appearing but have had no luck

```
insert overwrite table Demo partition (to_char(time,YYYY-MM-DD) = ${day}) SELECT * FROM Demo_staging;
```

I can see the data has appeared in my staging table but it does not make it to the actual table and I can only think of the partitioning being the reason for this.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried just a clean load from staging to actual table without using the partitioning, does that work as expected?

Comment: Also unsure if `to_char` is valid, you may want to try something like `date_format(time, 'yyyy-MM-dd') = '${day}'`.. may need to play with the formats a little bit..

Comment: No unfortunately even without the partition the data is still not being read from the staging table

Comment: Did you also try the `date_format` function mentioned in my earlier comment? Do you have any results from that?

Comment: I changed the partition data type to an int so hopefully this is no longer an issue

Comment: so is  this problem solved? Could you clarify for the benefit of others how you solved it (if so)?

Comment: No the data is still not being added from the staging table to the hive table, I don't think that the issue is in relation to the partitioning though as I have tried with and without the partition and still receive the same result